# How to ensure transaction management when updating two database

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, dao

How can ensure transaction is sucessfull in both database or none when connecting two different database(say one is mysql and other is oracle).

More Information..

I have a transaction where i will be updating two different database. Hence I have two different Service and two different DAO. How can i ensure transaction successfull in both DB or none..

Thanks
Chetan

Comment: You need to use distributed transactions. This is usually managed by an application server, but you can do it yourself using a `XADataSource`s but it adds some complications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "two phase commit".  You need a JTA transaction manager and XA JDBC drivers for both databases to make it work.

The wrinkle in your question is the word "service": if the two DAOs are encapsulated as separate web services, then JTA can't work.  Then the object that calls the two services will have to manage everything.  You'll have to create compensating transactions, keep track of success or failure of each call, and react accordingly.